# How to open a file in binmode with perl oneliner?

Tags: perl, batch-file

How to I open a file in binmode properly using batch and a perl oneliner?

`perl -p binmode("C:\test.txt")`

Gives:

`Can't open binmode(C:\test.txt): Invalid argument.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`open` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) with the [`:raw` layer](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html#%3araw). Untested:

```
perl -Mopen=IO,:raw …
```

Comment: `Unknown PerlIO layer class ':raw' (need IN, OUT or IO) at -e line 0.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`

Comment: @membersound Take a look at `perldoc open` and see: `perl -Mopen=IN,:raw ...` ;-)

Comment: `perl -0777 -Mopen=IN,:raw -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -e"print md5_hex(<>)" myfile`

Answer (score 2):

Without `-e`, a script name is expected, and no script named `binmode(C:\test.txt)` exists.

Note that `binmode(C:\test.txt)` is not valid Perl, so your command still won't work after adding the missing `-e`. You need to create a shell literal that creates the string `binmode("C:\test.txt")` or equivalent.

Finally, `binmode` takes a file handle, not a file name.

```
perl -pe"binmode(STDOUT); ..."
```

Of course, you only need to do it once, not once per line, so

```
perl -pe"BEGIN { binmode(STDOUT); } ..."
```

Comment: Of course, that's not valid perl either, as `binmode` does not take file name arguments.

Comment: @TLP, doh! yeah, didn't notice that. Fixed